# Can NOT use dependency after installing .jar into local Repositories with Maven3.0.3 in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a JAR which can't be found in the Maven Repositories.

So that I use the following command to install into my local repositories

```
install:install-file -Dfile=C:/FIXApplication/lib/quickfixj-all-1.5.2 -DgroupId=org.quickfixj -DartifactId=quickfixj -Dversion=1.5.2 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

And the result is successful and I can find the folder under the                                       .m2\repository\org\quickfixj\quickfixj

But when I modify the pom.xml to add the dependency.
It said:
    Missing artifact org.quickfixj:quickfixj:jar:1.5.2

Why this happen? Why can't read the local repositories?

Comment: Try running offline. mvn -o install

Comment: Have you checked that the jar is actually inside the m2 repository? I tried your command and left it unchanged and the installation was said to be successful however I do not have your jar and when I went to see if it was present in the M2 repo I saw that the directories had been created but there is no jar inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the command did not error, it is quite likely that the local repository does not have the artifact.

Your command has this part

```
-Dfile=C:/FIXApplication/lib/quickfixj-all-1.5.2
```

It should have been

```
-Dfile=C:/FIXApplication/lib/quickfixj-all-1.5.2.jar
```

Perhaps you can make this change, try again and see if it works.

Comment: The best way to known if it's there is to directly check your local maven repository for the proper file. Not only the folder, but also the contents.